# Perl warning while deleting files from directory if files doesn't exists

Tags: perl

I am trying to delete old log files from a directory.

Logic here is, if LOG directory doesn't exists create it; else delete files from LOG directory which is been created earlier.

```
...
use autodie;
my $logpath = "/home/Vinod/Test/LOG/";
if ( !-d $logpath ){
    make_path $logpath or die "Failed to create path: $logpath";
} else {
    unlink glob "$logpath/*.log";
}
...
```

So when the directory been already created and its empty I am getting below warning -

```
Can't unlink():  at script.pl line 41
```

How can I avoid this warning message when the directory already exists and empty. 
TIA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way would be to replace

```
unlink glob "$logpath/*.log";
```

with

```
my @files = glob "$logpath/*.log";
unlink @files if @files;
```

Comment: Note that this is merely a workaround for a bug in older versions of autodie. Newer version of autodie correctly handle empty lists passed to `unlink`.

Answer (score 3):

You are using an old version of the autodie module. Upgrade it to avoid this bug.

```
$ perl -e'use autodie; unlink "nonexistent.*"; CORE::say "ok"'
Can't unlink():  at -e line 1

$ cpan autodie
...
  TODDR/autodie-2.32.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- OK

$ perl -e'use autodie; unlink "nonexistent.*"; CORE::say "ok"'
ok
```

Comment: I am using module `File::Path`.

Comment: Yes, but the error isn't coming from `make_path`; it's coming from `unlink`. `unlink` doesn't normally emit an error message. You are using autodie to make it do so. But you are using a buggy version of autodie. Upgrade it and the problem goes away.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "an upgraded version". You mean one where this bug is fixed? Well, when you stop getting the error message! (I don't know what version fixed it.)

Comment: thanks for the explanation. But I don't have permission to install/upgrade the modules.

Comment: Installing modules doesn't require any special permissions. Either way, you already know how to work around the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Comment the `autodie` module. For creating the directory use `mkdir`, and for deleting the directory use `rmtree`. See below coding

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp;
use IO::All;
use File::Path;
use Win32;
#use autodie;
my $logpath = "G:/perl/StackOverflow/LOG";
if (!-d $logpath ){
    mkdir($logpath);
} else {
    unlink glob "$logpath/*.log";
    rmtree $logpath;
}
```